# Is it possible to run a join on a variable created by a sub-query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Right now I am running a sub-query to get the most recent status for a server, this sub-query is returning through the variable `last_status`.

```
 //This is ran when WithLastStatusDate() is called
$query->addSubSelect('last_status', ServerStatus::select('status_id')
    ->whereRaw('server_id = servers.id')
    ->latest()
);

$servers = Server::WithLastStatusDate()
    ->OrderBy('servers.id', 'desc')
    ->where('servers.isPublic', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

What I am trying to do now is do a join on this so that it gives me the actual name of the status based on the result of this query in the statuses table. I have tried to do a simple left join but am getting the error that the last_status column isn't found.

```
$servers = Server::WithLastStatusDate()
    ->OrderBy('servers.id', 'desc')
    ->where('servers.isPublic', '=', 1)
    ->leftjoin('statuses','servers.last_status', '=', 'statuses.id')
    ->get();
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

EDIT::

Server Table:

```
 Schema::create('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->boolean('isPublic');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Server_statuses Table:

```
Schema::create('server_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('server_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('server_id')->references('id')->on('servers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

statuses table:

```
Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('key');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

What $servers looks like after sub-query:

[image]

Raw SQL of query:

```
select `servers`.*, (select `status_id` from `server_statuses` where server_id = servers.id order by `created_at` desc limit 1) as `last_status` from `servers` where `servers`.`isPublic` = '1' order by `servers`.`id` desc
```

EDIT 2::

```
    $servers = DB::table('servers as sv')
        ->join('server_statuses as ss', 'sv.id', '=', 'ss.server_id')
        ->join('statuses as st', 'ss.status_id', '=', 'st.id')
        ->WithLastStatus()
        ->OrderBy('servers.id', 'desc')
        ->where('servers.isPublic', '=', 1)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Could you please add your tables structures and their fields?

Comment: @train_fox added the relevant tables also added screenshot of what the variable $servers looks like after sub-query

Comment: Could you please tell me what sql do you want to generate?

Comment: @train_fox Right now after the sub-query I have `last_status` has a 3 on that particular server, I need to do a join using that variable to the statuses table so that I can get the `status` (off the stauses table) of a server

Comment: Could you provide us the compiled query of your first example? (use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()`)

Comment: adding it now to the OP

Comment: I think it does come down to the execution order. You could probably put the whole query in another sub query and join on this one.

Comment: @Namoshek I tried running joins before the subscript but getting errors for columns not found. I didn't think refactoring this would take this long LOL

Comment: Added what I am now trying above, for some reason it is saying WithLastStatus() doesn't exist now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine LEFT JOINs with a subquery WHERE clause:

```
$servers = Server::select('servers.*', 'statuses.status as status_name')
    ->leftJoin('server_statuses', function($join) {
        $join->on('server_statuses.server_id', '=', 'servers.id')
            ->where('server_statuses.id', function($query) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from('server_statuses')
                    ->whereColumn('server_id', 'servers.id')
                    ->latest()
                    ->limit(1);
            });
    })
    ->leftJoin('statuses', 'statuses.id', '=', 'server_statuses.status_id')
    ->where('servers.isPublic', '=', 1)
    ->orderBy('servers.id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I dont have a statuses.name? what would go there instead, servers.name??

Comment: It should be `statuses.status`. That's what you meant with "actual name of the status", right?

Comment: correct, I have no idea why statuses.name confused me

Comment: That worked great! added approx 100ms of total response time but the page is dynamic now instead of hard coded! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since i'm not sure what exactly do you want to get from your query i going with a long solution and add some examples. With these tables you should have these models:
Server model:

```
class Server extends Model {
    public function statuses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'server_statuses');
    }
}
```

Status model:

```
class Status extends Model {
    public function servers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Server::class, 'server_statuses');
    }
}
```

**Examples:**
Get last status of server:

```
Server::find($serverId)->statuses()->latest()->first()->status;
```

Get all server statuses:

```
Server::find($serverId)->statuses;
```

Get server's specific status:

```
Server::find($serverId)->statuses()->where('status', 'SomeStatus')->get();
```

Get servers that have specific status:

```
Server::whereHas('statuses', function ($join) use ($status) {
    return $join->where('status', $status);
})->get();
```

Hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, both your `Server` and `Status` models have a `OneToMany` relationship to `ServerStatus`. In this case, you could fake a `OneToOne` relationship on your `Server` model which is selected as the latest row of `serverStatuses()`:

```
class Server
{
    public function serverStatuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServerStatus::class, 'server_id', 'id');
    }

    public function latestServerStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ServerStatus::class, 'server_id', 'id')
            ->latest(); // this is the most important line of this example
                        // `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` would do the same
    }
}

class ServerStatus
{
    public function server()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Server::class, 'server_id', 'id');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Status
{
    public function serverStatuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServerStatus::class, 'status_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

You can then also eager load the latest status for your servers as well as the status itself:

```
Server::with('latestServerStatus.status')->get();
```

Please be aware that `$server->latestServerStatus` is no collection but one object, just like in a normal `OneToOne` relation.

Comment: Since it is just a object not a collection would that make it so that I can only get one servers status at a time so that if I have say 100 servers that would be 100 different query calls?

Comment: No, that is exactly what this query optimizes for you. It will perform one query to get all `servers`, one query to get the latest `server_status` and one query to get the corresponding `statuses`. It doesn't matter how many servers you select, it will always be only 3 queries. You can observe the queries with `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` after you executed the queries.

Comment: Ill give it a shot and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: I implemented that and youre correct the number of query calls is only 3 but my memory usage is 100mb and my load time is 9 seconds. (it was <200ms previously)

Comment: Hm, it is of course loading quite some models. Maybe you can reduce it by only selecting relevant fields. Btw. is the query log enabled? It takes quite some resources as well.

Comment: I have been using DeBugBar to check my logs since the start of this project. I believe the issue is when running `SELECT * FROM 'server_statuses' WHERE 'server_statuses'.'server_id' in (1,2,3, etc) ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC` it has the longest run time.

Comment: Wow, okay. In this case Eloquent seems to mess up the query and selects all status updates, but does then only filter the most recent one for the relationship.

Comment: It seems so, and I have over 500k statuses being entered in a year. This is running with only 50k, may be an issue lol